# Как можно улучшить эту типизацию?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Имеется следующий тип:

```
export type Country = {
  name: 'USA' | 'Russia' | 'Bulgaria' | 'Romania' | 'Austria' | 'Great Britain' | 'Italy',
  code: 'us' | 'ru' | 'bg' | 'ro' | 'au' | 'gb' | 'it'
};
```

Однако при его использовании можно создать объект с любыми перечисленными `name` и `code`, например:

```
{ name: USA, code: 'ru'}
```

Понятное дело, что так не годится. Как сделать связанные значения `name` и `code`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[песочница там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&esModuleInterop=false&declaration=false&ssl=33&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/CoUQysBcAEDeCwAoaLoBcCeAHAptAJAMYD2ArgHZoBOG0AvEqk9AD5zTkCGAtjjAOQBVMAEF+AGmgkAJn2j9SAZ37QAvo2Yo2sDjzn8ASksUBLThKnFZAqqRXrkm1uy68BAIVIAbAOacqZhYy+gBGPvYamtq6bvIGxNyc5IGSwTbEEY5RLnoCIkrUKZbW8px2apHM0a76AOJUOJxo0O4BaJwm5EFW+j4hmU7OOjUCAJLtXhjdJfwmaPYA3JUA9MvQALTi65UAPERklDQAfMO58uOck9P6c4uDKKvQxADWK2t7JBTUGCcxdQ1NFptDpdVI9dJ3R7AbA4EBUKjEKhIBxIUAQGAILKWciKZoAYQA8oIAHLAAwATXocEqTCEon4AiUEhpqEMxkCNjs4hZKH4nl8-g58jCzKxtPiiWS5gh3LFrPyuIC0tKXJ58nqjWarTmIIZ8j6osG-AuVwEt1lTFU0E4imxuLeG2gW0qmFwBE+h1odHQMOIADNoISSWTyQ7NhtKiQcc0lDB9l8aABtOliAC6VIUyk0jxeqAdUdx0ARcY932TEqSgXT3szKihMLhCKRWMe4e2LbW6yd7aYBeafSpQdJFOTGsB2vanX46cefegfRgACI+ovkUA)

```
TEST: {
    type $country =
        | { name: 'USA', code: 'us' }
        | { name: 'Russia', code: 'ru' }
        | { name: 'Bulgaria', code: 'bg' }
        | { name: 'Romania', code: 'ro' }
        | { name: 'Austria', code: 'au' }
        | { name: 'Great Britain', code: 'gb' }
        | { name: 'Italy', code: 'it' };
    // -,-
    <$country>{ name: 'Italy', code: 'it' };          // ok
    // <$country>{ name: 'Great Britain', code: 'ro' }; // TypeError
}
```

```
TEST: {
    const COUNTRY = {
        'USA': 'us',
        'Russia': 'ru',
        'Bulgaria': 'bg',
        'Romania': 'ro',
        'Austria': 'au',
        'Great Britain': 'gb',
        'Italy': 'it',
    } as const
    // - ,-
    type $country = typeof COUNTRY
    // -, -
    const us: $country['USA'] = 'us'      // ok   
    // const ro: $country['Romania'] = 'us' // TypeError
    // -, -
    // - ,-
    const gb = COUNTRY['Great Britain'] // const gb: "gb"
}
```

---

доки:

- https://www.staging-typescript.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions
- `as const`

  - TS 34+
  - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions
- enums - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums